# Android studio gradle error: failed to apply plugin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

So my app has current issue with the gradle and failing to build however it does sync fine. So I've updated all build tools and all support tools. The it comes up with is:

Error:(1, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
>   Gradle version 2.10 is required. Current version is 2.8. If using the gradle wrapper, try editing the distributionUrl in C:\Users\pat\Documents\CoinFlip\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties to gradle-2.10-all.zip

however i have already changed the gradle version to 2.10:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

my top gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha5'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

The file which the error sends me:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "patrickbarber.coinflip"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),    'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
}
```

Any help will be appreciated Ive tried many things but nothing seems to work. I did try to change the Android_daily_override but i didnt know where it was.

thank you

Comment: use `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha2'`  & call `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

Comment: i Know get the error Error:(1, 0) Plugin is too old, please update to a more recent version, or set ANDROID_DAILY_OVERRIDE environment variable to "efdc9743630b8ba5a00eaeaa1375fff7cdb0e3cb"
<a href="fixGradleElements">Fix plugin version and sync project</a><br><a href="openFile:C:\Users\pat\Documents\CoinFlip\app\build.gradle">Open File</a>